# Global variable in JavaScript not set when using getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here's my code. If i check "pranks" variable by "google inspector" all works fine.
But the "alert" on the last line show a 0-size array!
I mucking with local/global variables?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() { 

 pranks = [];

function getAllPranks(){


    $.getJSON('list.json', function(data) {

      $.each(data['pranks'], function(key, val) {
        pranks.push(val);
      });

    });

}

 $(document).ready(function(){


    getAllPranks();

    alert(pranks.length);

 });


 }());
 </script>
```

Comment: Please search for "jquery return value from ajax". The answer will be there.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2960417/getjson-and-variable-scope-in-javascript , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4158865/javascript-global-variable-problem , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3537434/cant-get-correct-return-value-from-an-jquery-ajax-call

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I return a variable from a $.getJSON function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31129/how-can-i-return-a-variable-from-a-getjson-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking your code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
(function() { 
    function getAllPranks( callback ) {
        $.getJSON('list.json', function(data) {
            $.each(data['pranks'], function(key, val) {
                pranks.push(val);
            });
            callback( pranks );
        });
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){
        getAllPranks( function( pranks ) {
            alert(pranks.length);
        } );
    });
}());
</script>
```

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous. This means the callback function (`function(data)`) is executed once the result comes back. When you execute `alert(pranks.length)`, the function has not executed because the response hasn't come back at this moment.

Answer (score 3):

Change it to:

```
$.getJSON('list.json', function(data) {
  $.each(data['pranks'], function(key, val) {
    pranks.push(val);
  });
  alert(pranks.length); /* pranks has data now */
});
```